# Score Multiplier By Time

Tags: time, multiplication, unity-game-engine, seconds

Here is my score manager script I made:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

     public Text scoreText;

     public float scoreCount; // What the score is when the scene first loads. I set this as zero.

     public float pointsPerSecond; // Every second, the points increase by THIS amount. Right now it is 100.

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

         scoreCount += pointsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

         scoreText.text = "" + Mathf.Round (scoreCount); // It comes out as a float with like 6 decimals; I round to an nice, clean Integer 

     }
 }
```

My problem that I cannot figure out how to solve is: How do I make a multiplier that multiplies the score by times two after 30 seconds of the game, then multiplies the score by times three after 1 minute, then times four after 1 Minute and 30 seconds, then finally, times five after 2 minutes? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect opportunity to use an `IEnmurator` function.  These are methods you can call, which you can tell to wait for a certain period of time before resuming.  So in your case, you could have an `IEnumerator` function the multiplies your score every thirty seconds.  For example:

```
public Text scoreText;

public float scoreCount; // What the score is when the scene first loads. I set this as zero.

public float pointsPerSecond; // Every second, the points increase by THIS amount. Right now it is 100.

private int scoreMultiplier = 1;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(MultiplyScore());
}

// Update is called once per frame
 void Update () 
{

     scoreCount += pointsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

     scoreText.text = "" + Mathf.Round (scoreCount); // It comes out as a float with like 6 decimals; I round to an nice, clean Integer 

 }

IEnumerator MultiplyScore()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(30);
        scoreMultiplier++;
        scoreCount *= scoreMultiplier;
    }
}
```

Note, if you only want to go up to 5 times multiplication you can use the score multiplier variable as the condition in your `IEnumerator` while-loop like so:

```
IEnumerator MultiplyScore()
{
    while(scoreMultiplier < 5)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(30);
        scoreMultiplier++;
        scoreCount *= scoreMultiplier;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private float multiplier = 2.0f;
void Start(){
    InvokeRepeating("SetScore", 30f, 30f);
}
void SetScore(){
    score *= multiplier;
    multiplier += 1f;
    if(multiplier > 5.5f) // Added 0.5f margin to avoid issue of float inaccuracy
    {  
        CancelInvoke()
    } 
}
```

InvokeRepeating sets the first call (second parameter) and the frequency (third parameter), in your case it is 30s and also 30s. Then once the multiplier is too big (greater than 5), you cancel the invoke.

If your multiplier is an integer, you can remove the margin and use a round number.